# Java x*0.01 is not the same as x/100.0, why?

Tags: java

Why is:

```
Math.round(6.0/11.0*10000.0)*0.01  // = 54.550000000000004
```

but

```
Math.round(6.0/11.0*10000.0)/100.0 // = 54.55
```

And what would be the right way to round this correctly.
For example I have int x, int y and I need a rounded x/y*100 on 2 decimal points.
Thank you.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: 54.55 can't be represented exactly in binary so both calculations will be slightly inexact. If you want to **display** the number rounded you should ask about that. You'll never get the `double` itself to be exactly 54.55.